# ssl error preventing apache from starting

Tags: ssl, httpd

Today I installed monit on a production server because mysqld periodically falls over.
After a few hours, monit tried to restart apache, but failed, and I am unable to start it manually.

The error is:

```
[error] Unable to configure verify locations for client authentication
[Sat Dec 12 05:32:49 2015] [error] SSL Library Error: 151441510 error:0906D066:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:bad end line
[Sat Dec 12 05:32:49 2015] [error] SSL Library Error: 185090057 error:0B084009:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:PEM lib
```

A check of file dates shows that none of the certificate files have suddenly been corrupted (all have dates from a month ago), nor has /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf

I think I successfully restarted apache about a week ago.
What is the best way to get the site up again (with or without SSL)

Mysql version - 5.5.46
CentOS version - 6.7
Apache version - 2.2.15

Comment: It's probably a long shot - but check the expiry date of your CRL file: `openssl crl -text -noout -in filename.crl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end it was an error in the ca-bundle file formatting. I had discounted that initially, because the site had been working happily for a month on https: Go figure.

Comment: Let me do as you said: "Go figure"  :)